# How can I merge two ItemGroups in MSBuild

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, compilation

I have two ItemGroups:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="A.cs" />
    <Compile Include="B.cs" />
    <Compile Include="C.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PEG Include="A.cs" />
    <PEG Include="Y.cs" />
    <PEG Include="Z.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I need to do add each of the items in `PEG` to `Compile` IF AND ONLY IF that item is not AREADY in `Compile`.

Is there an easy way to do that?

My first attempt is something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="%(PEG.Identity)" Condition=" '$(Compile)' != '%(PEG.Identity)' " />
</ItemGroup>
```

But that doesn't work for obvious reasons.  I don't really want to do a manual anti-join in MSBuild.

Perhaps using `Exclude` would work?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured it out.

The first thing I was doing wrong, was using `$(Compile)` rather than `@(Compile)`.

Next, I was on the right track with the `Exclude` property.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Compile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="A.cs" />
    <Compile Include="B.cs" />
    <Compile Include="C.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Compile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PEG Include="A" />
        <PEG Include="D" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Compile = @(Compile)" />
    <Message Text="PEG     = @(PEG)" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="%(PEG.Identity).cs" Exclude="@(Compile)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Compile = @(Compile)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

After this is done, `Compile` contains `A.cs;B.cs;C.cs;D.cs` as desired.